# Does rend stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do damage over time effects stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/do-damage-over-time-effects-stack)

The ability "Rend" makes your target bleed for 3 second. What happens if you consequently use the spell? Will the damage stack or is it a waste of rage to use the spell consequently?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66936/5291](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66936/5291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will refresh the timer on the rend debuff, not apply a totally separate effect. However, you will still get the initial damage, and if two separate barbs apply a rend, you will have 2 rend debuffs.

Comment: Is there a way to see this in game?  I don't see buffs/debuffs below monster portraits at all.

Comment: Unfortunately no, or we'd have much more concrete answers to questions beyond observation. I can tell you this, if 1 barb applies rend it ticks quickly, if two barbs apply, it ticks even faster. If a single barb applies it rapidly, it does not tick any faster, but will refresh how long the effect lasts.