# Does "Rend" stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does rend stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68498/does-rend-stack)

Does the Barbarian skill “Rend” stack? If not then it is waste of fury to cast it more again before the previous cast ended?

How should this skill be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't stack on top of your own rend.

Two Barbarians can cast rend and they will stack, but casting rend again on your own will only refresh the current rend, not add a new DoT.

This is actually how majority of DoT's work in Diablo 3, they will all refresh themselves but not stack, unless two different characters cast the same spell.

The only exception I can think of is Magic Weapon - Venom for Wizards, it will stack on itself.

Comment: Thanks, but is this skill then actually viable to use as it doesn't do that great damage...

Comment: @georgelappies The damage is average.  With the life regeneration rune, it can be very useful for a kiting strategy.  The downside of this skill is that it is not a "Spam" button when your fury is full.  When fighting a lot of monsters at once, it can be very good with cleave (farming an area that is easy for you).  When playing difficult content, the heal can be very useful with a kite & tank strat.