# Hidden modifiers to various stats in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been reading around and found various topics on different hidden modifiers to stats/attributes in Diablo 3. Some of the ones I found most confusing include the Life oh Hit (LoH) modifier, which is based on the skill you are using. Others include lifesteal modifiers for higher difficulties, monster HP and damage modifiers and more people join the game, etc.

My question is whether or not there is some place where all this information is compiled, or where people are getting answers from. For example, is there a list of all the LoH modifiers for every single skill? Is there a list of the lifesteal modifier for each difficulty (I already found that it is 70% for Nightmare, 40% for Hell, and 20% for Inferno, but I'm still wondering where this information comes from)? Is there a website that lists the different damage formulas, and how DoT (damage over time) effects stack (or don't stack) with each other?

Overall, I'm basically looking for something like a game guide which explains what each stat does (including secondary stats like resistances, armor, etc), and what modifiers exist on them in each of the difficulties. I know that for Diablo II and Titan Quest, these weren't provided by the game makers, but were instead discovered by the players and later posted somewhere so everyone could access it.

Comment: Although this site isn't comprehensive, it does contain the answers to some of your questions if you search a bit. For example, the answer about the lifesteal modifier per difficulty level, with reference, can be found [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69894/8462), and there's also a question about DoT stacking [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66936/8462)

Comment: Oh, yes. I actually found those two already, but I was wondering if there was anything that amounts to a Diablo 3 wiki, which explains these mechanics in greater detail. The site http://www.diablo-3-wiki.com/ appears to have outdated beta information, and is largely incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of sites that have similar information to what you want.  Part of the problem may be that some of this information is already published.  For example, the life steal changes by difficulty information comes from http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#life-steal

#### Official Game Guide

- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/

#### Wikis

- http://www.diablowiki.net/
- http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_Wiki
- http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Diablo_III_Wiki

#### Calculators

- http://www.d3rawr.com/
- http://d3up.com/
- http://theasiangamer.com/d3-damage-calculator/

#### Builds

- http://diablo.somepage.com/popular/
- http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/p/diablo-3-wizard-builds.html

There doesn't seem to be anything organized in the direction that you want.  I.e. there's nothing that lists all the affixes and then explains everything about them.  Perhaps it's still too early in the game's lifetime.  The closest that I found was http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Steal -- but much of the information still seems to be scattered.  For example, click on [magical suffixes](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Suffix#Life_Stolen_Per_Hit) and the click through to [Leech](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Leech), [Locust](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Locust), or [Lamprey](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Lamprey_%28magic_suffix%29).  They tell you that skeletons don't have life to steal, but Life Steal itself doesn't tell you that.

It's been more than a year since you asked this question, and no one has stepped up to make the index that you want.  The information may be out there, but people will still have to search for it.