# Does a weapon's "bleed" affix stack with the Barbarian skill "Rend"?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I've noticed that some weapons have an affix that states "***X.X%* chance to inflict Bleed for *XXX-XXX* damage over 5 seconds**".  This seems like a cheap way to increase my DPS especially against monsters with a lot of hitpoints, but I tend to use the Barbarian skill "Rend" which also inflicts a Bleed effect.  Answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/do-damage-over-time-effects-stack) seem to imply that stacking DoTs is not possible for one given ability - however I'm unclear on whether this counts as the same ability since it is a Bleed effect, but from a separate source.

I suspect there must be other similar cases with Poison effects and others which apply to different classes, however I am not aware of specific examples.

Comment: I think they do, there are a lot of rend barbs right now loving Skorn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It counts as two separate dots, so yes they both work. The bleed on your weapon however is unaffected by any of the modifiers that affect your Rend. It's just an auxiliary effect.